# Why an intersection observer doesn't observe the second element?

Tags: reactjs, intersection-observer

codesandbox example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-wozniak-3qih8p?file=/src/Progress.tsx

I am trying to use the Intersection Observer API to track both the first and last elements of my list. My goal is to display either a left or right button based on the horizontal scroll position.
However, I have run into an issue where the intersection observer is only tracking the first element and I am unsure why this is happening and how to correct it.

Comment: You codesandbox works fine for me ^^ Besides that this is one of the cases where I would break the React patterns and do some vanilla DOM manipulation in a useEffect in order to reduce checks / repaints (i.e. toggling the classes of the always present arrows based on the scroll position).

Comment: Setting aside how much fun it is to work with IntersectionObserver, @moonwave99's approach would be simpler and much more portable. It would be quite straightforward to add event listeners for `scroll` events and adjust classes accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs, the IntersectionObserver callback is called with:

> **entries**
> An array of IntersectionObserverEntry objects, each representing one threshold which was crossed, either becoming more or less visible than the percentage specified by that threshold.

So, you do not necessarily receive both `[first, last]` elements in the callback – just those whose amount of intersection has changed.

As a rough cut you might use something like:

```js
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      entries => {
        const lookup = new Map(entries.map(entry => [entry.target, entry.isIntersecting]));
        setLeftVisible(!lookup.get(leftRef.current!));
        setRightVisible(!lookup.get(rightRef.current!));
      },
      ...
    );
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-monad-jk0kt7)

Answer (score 1):

This might be because you are observing the left and right arrow with same intersection observer instance. One possible fix can be making two separate instances for both arrows.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!progressRef || !leftRef.current || !rightRef.current) return;

    const leftObserver = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
      setLeftVisible(!entry.isIntersecting);
    }, {
      root: progressRef.current,
      rootMargin: "0px",
      threshold: 1
    });

    const rightObserver = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
      setRightVisible(!entry.isIntersecting);
    }, {
      root: progressRef.current,
      rootMargin: "0px",
      threshold: 1
    });

    leftObserver.observe(leftRef.current);
    rightObserver.observe(rightRef.current);

    return () => {
      leftObserver.disconnect();
      rightObserver.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: It works fine, thank you. Fortunately, we found a solution with one instance

Answer (score 1):

A solution without IntersectionObserver:

```js
function useArrows() {
  const progressRef = useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null);
  const leftArrowRef = useRef<HTMLLIElement>(null);
  const rightArrowRef = useRef<HTMLLIElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const ref = progressRef.current;
    if (!ref) {
      return;
    }

    function onScroll(event: Event) {
      const {
        scrollLeft,
        offsetWidth,
        scrollWidth
      } = event.currentTarget as HTMLElement;

      const reachedStart = scrollLeft === 0;
      const reachedEnd = offsetWidth + scrollLeft >= scrollWidth;
      leftArrowRef.current?.classList.toggle("invisible", reachedStart);
      rightArrowRef.current?.classList.toggle("invisible", reachedEnd);
    }

    ref.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    return () => {
      ref.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    };
  }, []);
  return {
    progressRef,
    leftArrowRef,
    rightArrowRef
  };
}
```

You may want to throttle the `onScroll` function of course.

[See example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-ride-p2hznx?file=/src/Progress.tsx)